# Android how to draw a custom Round Rect?

Tags: android, canvas, paint

I've tried looking for a solution to this but no dough.
I want to achieve this:

[image]

But instead I get:

[image]

I want the bottom to be straight with no curves. Essentially right after the little segment after the bottom right corner, I want the two lines to be straight to create that message pop-up effect, and then back to round again. I tried looking it up to no avail.

```
CornerPathEffect corEffect = new CornerPathEffect(radius);
mainPath = new Path();
mainPath.moveTo(coords[0].getX(), coords[0].getY());
paint.setPathEffect(corEffect);
for(int j= 1; j < coords.length; j++) {
    mainPath.lineTo(coords[j].getX(), coords[j].getY());
}
mainPath.close();
```

In my code I'm using classes CornerPathEffect as well as class Path to achieve this so far. I call canvas drawPath() method. I have the canvas translated to the (x,y) coordinates so I can map my coordinates relative to (0, 0).

I tried calling the moveTo() method on the origin after the 3rd segment and drawing a line from the origin to the bottom left, but it leaves a weird gap between the origin.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: why not just use a 9-patch?

Comment: Never heard of it. Plus I need to dynamically change the color of the box, so that wouldn't be an option I think, I'm really stuck here...

Comment: it depends on what you're trying to do, but you can probably change the color using a Porter-Duff filter.

Comment: I'll take a look at that. If it matters, this is for an Android Wear watch face.